# Img1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I want to set an image in my ANDROID project but there is an error:

I've used this line in order to define an image in my JAVA file. (`ImageView` already created in the XML file).

```
ImageView imgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.Img1);
```

Also, I used this line in my XML file:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/Img1" android:scaleType="fitXY" 
    android:layout_weight="200dp" android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

But when I use this line, I get this error message:

> Img1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

I've cleaned my project without any success.

Comment: use R.id.Img1
`ImageView imgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img1);`

Comment: I've used that but nothing changed.

Comment: If you don't update your question, it seems that you are still using `android.R.id.Img1`

Comment: @Vuger I said that in my project, I've used R.id.Img1 instead of android.R.id.Img1 but the error already exists.

Comment: Just remove this code -- import android.R;

Comment: and just use ctrl+shift+o after that

Comment: and also get a good java book then an android book...

Comment: @sandy I've tried your solution, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Android's R file, instead you should use "your.package.name.R.Img1", that way the reference will point to the right R file

```
ImageView imgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(your.package.name.R.id.Img1);
```

Replace "you.package.name" with whatever string you are using in the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package.name"
```

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Comment: It should work, if not, it means your project has errors and the R file is not being generated...

Comment: That is right. R.java not exists. I've cleaned the project but it doesn't generate. Is there any problem with my Eclipse?

Comment: Also in 'setContentView(android.R.layout.main);' I have this error: main cannot be resolved or is not a field. Is this related to R.java file? and perhaps my eclipse?

Comment: You have the same problem android.R.layout.main will not exist, you need to set your.package.name.R.layout.main...

Answer (score 0):

Since the imageview is defined in your own project as opposed to the default android object, then you should call is using:

```
ImageView imgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed!